# Странное поведение данных из API при использовании Retrofit и Coroutines

Tags: coroutine

Учусь работать с корутинами.
Есть функция в репозиторииЖ

```
 override suspend fun fetchHero(): Deferred<List<Hero>> {

    return GlobalScope.async {

        val listHeroStstsFromApi = ProviderImpl.getHeroStats().await()
        val listHeroEntityFromDB = roomAppDatabase.heroDao().fetchHeroes()

        if (listHeroEntityFromDB.isEmpty()) {
            listHeroStstsFromApi.map {
                roomAppDatabase.heroDao().insertHero(HeroConverterImpl.convertApiToDB(it))
                println("AAAA  герои в базу данных из ретрофита: ${it::class.java.simpleName}")
                HeroConverterImpl.convertApiToUI(it)
            }
        } else listHeroEntityFromDB.map {
            println("AAAA герои из базы данных: ${it::class.java.simpleName}")
            HeroConverterImpl.convertDBtoUI(it)
        }

    }
}
```

Это функция для вытягивания героев.
Такая же функция для игроков.

При первой инсталяции  и вызове fetchHero() вывод в logcat очень странный:

AAA  герои в базу данных из ретрофита: HeroStatApi  - повторяется 8 раз

AAA игроки в базу данных из ретрофита: PlayersApi - 
19 (!!!) раз!

Как такое может быть?

Апи сервис:

```
@GET("./heroStats")
fun getHeroesStats(): Deferred<List<HeroStatApi>>
```

Ретрофит:

```
.addConverterFactory(Json.nonstrict.asConverterFactory("application/json".toMediaType()))
        .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
        .build()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваш запрос getHeroesStats возвращает список

Когда вы его получаете, вы вызываете на нем метод котлина map, который в свою очередь производит какую-то операцию с каждым элементом списка, в вашем случае логирование, сохранение в бд и конвертирует.

Аналогично и со вторым методом

Вот потому у вас в логе по 19 и 8 элементов, по размеру списков.

Вот тут про то как работает функция map:
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/index.html